# Margins around wtf.form_field within bootstrap panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

When I output my form using quick_form, I get a nice margin around the form as shown below.

```
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form, form_type="basic") }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Nice margins with quick_form]

However the quick_form method doesn't give me the level of control I need over the form and therefore I need to output form fields individually. When I do this however I don't get any margins around the form fields.

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">

            <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
                <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.floors) }}</div>
                <div>{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}</div>
            </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: No margins]

How do I retain the margins in the second example above?

Comment: Try to remove form-horizontal class from your form, it will act as if your using a row class. Your form does not seem to be horizontal.

Comment: @DavidDomain : Thanks! That did it! Just replaced "form form-horizontal" with "form form-group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by DavidDomain, the problem I was observing was caused due to form-horizontal form definition. Defining the form as form-group resolved the problem with the margins.